# How do I LINQ order a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of class objects:

```
Tests
```

This collection contains many `Test` instances:

```
public class Test {
   public string column1 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use LINQ to order the contents of `Tests` and put into a new collection called `TestsOrdered`.  I want to order by the contents of `column1`. I would like to do this with LINQ as later I want to add more to the ordering.

How can I do this with LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ:

```
var result =
from test in tests
orderby test.column1
select test;
```

Fluent :

```
var result = tests.OrderBy(x => x.column1);
```

Comment: Both are Linq, the first is Query syntax, and the second is method syntax.

Comment: Agree that both are Linq. But second is Fluent syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) or [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916.aspx) (if you want to sort in descending direction)

```
var TestsOrdered = tests.OrderBy(x => x.column1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
// .. fill your list
testList = testList.OrderBy(x => x.column1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var TestsOrdered = Tests.OrderBy( t => t.column1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do it like this:

```
var TestsOrdered = Tests.OrderBy( t => t.column1 );
```